# screen freezes with basic flutter App in Android 7.1.1( API25)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I created sample counter Flutter App that gets created on 'File-New-New Flutter Project' in Android studio. When I run that app on
AVDs that is with Android 7.1.1 ( Tried with **Pixel-3 with API 25** and Pixel with API 25 ), and when the app goes in back ground and comes back, the state is **lost** as shown in [image: Android7.1.1] and app becomes unresponsive where counter can not go higher than 2.

The same counter App with Android 8 (API 26) and above it works fine as [image: Android8] as counter can be continued beyond 2.

What should one do to support Android 7.1.1 . This problem applications and is reproducible on Windows 10 emulator.

Comment: Found that this might something todo with GPU rendering so raised a ticket in flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64309

Comment: There is another/similar at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35900